# How to setup CI with App Center if I have private dependencies in my project managed with SPM?

Tags: ios, continuous-integration

I am trying to setup CI with App Center for my App. The App has few package dependencies and one of them is private but inside my organisation. The dependencies are managed through SPM. I connected my GitHub account where all the private apps and dependencies are located. But, the build on App Center fails because of missing public key, because the mentioned dependencies are pulled with SSH.

Is there any way to set some keys from my repo on GitHub to AppCenter or to grant some permission? Seems that AppCenter can't handle SPM dependencies build if any of them is private.

Bellow is an example of the error:

> 2023-01-23 14:03:12.081 xcodebuild[1922:7455]
> Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/ResultBundle_2023-23-01_14-03-0012.xcresult skipping cache due to an error: Failed to clone repository git@github.com:my-app/my-app.git:     Cloning into bare repository '/Users/runner/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm/repositories/my-app-0fe0f1ea'...git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

> skipping cache due to an error: Failed to clone repository git@github.com:my-app/my-app.git:     Cloning into bare repository '/Users/runner/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm/repositories/my-app-0fe0f1ea'...

> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.     Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

> xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies: Failed to clone repository git@github.com:my-app/my-app.git: Cloning into bare repository '/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-adedabdybispofpuztbywfdmxtd/SourcePackages/repositories/my-app-0fe0f1ea'...